# Windows Input Simulator Library not being invoked via Windows Service

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-services

I am using Windows Input Simulator(http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) in my .Net 2.0 project.
When I run the application through the Visual Studio Debugger, I am able to call the methods in the Windows Input Simulator library but when I run my project as a Windows Service, I am not able to call any of the above mentioned library's methods.

Do I need to register this Windows Input Simulator DLL somewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: Windows Services run in a different WindowStation/Session and don't have anything to do with the desktop you see so using this library in a Windows Service is rather "pointless" IMHO.

Comment: There is an option while setting up the Log ON properties for the service to "Allow the service to interact with the desktop" but that doesn't seem to help as well.

Comment: That depends on what you want to do... you didn't describe your goal, just some problem with a library...

Comment: @nits - You may be able to have your service monitor windows session state and launch a helper process which uses the library.

Comment: @M.Babcock - By helper process, do you mean another application or a thread belonging to the same service.

Comment: @nits - It will need to be another *process* (whether it's defined in the same executable assembly or not is up to you). As Yahia stated, this just can't work from a service so you'll need to launch a separate process in the user's session in order to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your program as a windows service it's running on another desktop so it cannot send keys to the desktop you see.